# Tracing MovieClips Name

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating some MovieClips like so:

```
var AClip:A = new A();
var A2Clip:A2 = new A2();
var A3Clip:A3 = new A3();
```

I then put the above into an array and am trying to trace out thier "name".

```
for(var i:int=0;i<theArray.length;i++){
        trace(theArray[i].name);
    }
```

This traces

```
instance99
instance77
instanceN...
```

What I want to accomplish is the trace is tracing out what I "initialized" them to

```
AClip
A2Clip
A3Clip
```

Is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable's name is not the same as MovieClip's name. You have to set its name manualy:

```
var AClip:A = new A();
var A2Clip:A2 = new A2();
var A3Clip:A3 = new A3();
AClip.name = "AClip";
A2Clip.name = "A2Clip";
A3Clip.name = "A3Clip";
```

Then you can get their name by calling *trace(theArray[i].name);*